# Remove Uncommitted New Rows Of DGV

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have **unbound DGV** and I wants to remove unwanted last row of it on DGV Leave EventHandller. How to do it?.

I know to add new rows to dgv by programmatically and setting the property AllowUserToAddRows = false.

But my question is : is it possible to remove last row of DGV without setting property AllowUserToAddRows = false?.

OR

### Is it possible to remove uncommitted new rows of DGV?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the DataGridView `AllowUserToAddRows`  property to `False`.

However you'll have to provide a method which will allow the user to enter a new row. For example you can have that when the user double click the DataGridView, you set AllowUserToAddRows to true. And then when they are done editing, you set the value back to False.

**To Add a new Row:**

Lets say your DataGridView is called MyDataGridView and you have a Button called BtnAddRow and when the button is clicked, it adds an new row to your DataGridView.

```
private void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       // Add an empty row
       MyDataGridView.Rows.Add();
}
```

Alternatively, you could just handle DataGridView `OnDoubleClick` event in which you can call `MyDataGridView.Rows.Add()` to add a new row.

Comment: @Jean-Louise, Ok than how can you add a rows to dgv for data entry?

Comment: Lets say you have a DataGridView called MyDataGridView. You can programmatically add a new row to it like this: `MyDataGridView.Rows.Add()`

Comment: @Jean-Louis, Yes You are right but think that it is waste the time of user. If you have complete DGV infront of you than why you have to do unnecessary extra job?. I wants to know  is it possible to remove last row without set allowUserToAddRows = False

Comment: @mahesh: Since the button click which bothers you, then just replace it with for example a double click on the DataGridView which adds a new row. It an idea that you can adapt to something that will suit your requirements

Comment: @Jean-Louis, myup vote for your right guidence but make sure that it is not my question answer I just want to know that is it possible without set allowUserToAddRows=false?

Comment: @mahesh: This is the best solution in can think of. Just as AS-CII said, that last row is present to allow the user to add new rows. And if you dont want if there, you have to disable through setting AllowUserToAddRows to False. You go around the fact that user can't automatically add new row by providing a programmatic way of doing so. You do that through an event handler in which you add the code I gave you up there.

Answer (score 3):

If your DataGridView is bound to a DataSet, this does the trick for deleting the current row:

```
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
    MyDataSet1.MyTable.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).RejectChanges()
Else
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove uncommitted new rows in datagrid view by setting AllowUserToAddRows = false

grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove last row on DGV Leave Event.

Just attach an handler on `DataGridView.Leave` event and use this code:

```
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int count = dgv.Rows.Count;
     dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(count - 1);
}
```

**EDIT:** Are you referring to the last blank row that appears in the DataGridView? If yes it is there to allow the user to create new rows. To disable it follow the suggestion of Jean-Luis setting `AllowUserToAddRows` property to `false`.

Comment: It's throw InvalidOperation Exception like "Uncomitted new row cannot be delited.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with removing the "last" row from a `DataGridView`. I solved it like this.

```
grid.Rows.RemoveAt(grid.Rows.Count - 2);
```

It skips the last row which is the uncommitted new row that throws an exception if you try to remove it.

To remove several rows:

```
while (new_count < grid.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    grid.Rows.RemoveAt(grid.Rows.Count - 2);
}
```

Therefore, no need to set `AllowUserToAddRows = false`.